# function wont execute when the button is pressed on PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, function, pysimplegui, coinbase-api

I have made a program that executes a market order trade by utilizing the Coinbase Crypto Exchange Sandbox API. This code works fine when I execute it without a GUI. However, I want to create a GUI for it so I can execute some of the features without having to run through the code- more user-friendly and functional.

The problem: Since making a basic GUI and putting the market order/buy code into a function I cant execute trades.

I have tried calling the function and changing the position of the code.

I have a hunch it is not executing the Buy order due to the Buy order code being separate from the rest of the code.
I tried putting all the code into the Buy order function but it still didn't work.

Any ideas or thoughts are welcome. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import cbpro
import PySimpleGUI as sg    

api_secret = 
api_key =  
api_pass =

# creates client variable
url='https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com'

client = cbpro.AuthenticatedClient(
    api_key,
    api_secret,
    api_pass,
    api_url=url
)
```

Accessing certain values

```
#websocket
class TextWebsocketClient(cbpro.WebsocketClient):
    # Connection to Website
    def on_open(self):
        self.url           = 'wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com'  #connection endpoint
        self.message_count = 0
    
    # creates message for onscreen
    def on_message(self,msg):   
        self.message_count += 1
        msg_type = msg.get('type',None)
        if msg_type == 'ticker':
            # returns a dict of keys&values.
            # we then select the ones we want- 'time','price',ect
            time_val   = msg.get('time',('-'*27))
            price_val  = msg.get('price',None)
            if price_val is not None:
                price_val = float(price_val)
            product_id = msg.get('product_id',None)
            
            print(f"{time_val:40} {price_val:.3f} {product_id}\tchannel type: {msg_type}")
    
    def on_close(self):
        print(f"<---Websocket connection closed--->\n\tTotal messages: {self.message_count}")
        
# 

# Closes after n messages or when loses connection or closed

stream = TextWebsocketClient(products=['BTC-USD'],channels=['ticker'])
stream.start()

#stream.close()
print ("Stream closed")
```

Placing a buy order.
I put this into a function that doesn't now work but the same code works fine when not in a function or a part of the GUI.

```
#Placing a BUY market order
# Buy
def buy():
    client.place_market_order(product_id='BTC-USD',side='buy',funds=100)
    accounts = client.get_accounts()
    
    for acc in accounts:
        currency = acc.get('currency')
        if currency=='BTC':
            acc_id = acc.get('id')


    acc_history = client.get_account_history(acc_id)
    return "Buy Complete"
```

GUI below

```
# GUI 
#LAYOUT
theme_name_list = sg.theme('DarkGreen')
#Buttons
layout = [ 
            [sg.Text("Welcome to your Crypto Launch Pad!\n Select a command...")],
            [sg.Button('Buy')],
            [sg.Button('Sell')],
            [sg.Button('Current Price')],
            [sg.Button('Profit/Loss')],
            [sg.Button('Exit')]
    
         ]
 
window = sg.Window('Crypto Buy/Sell Launch Pad', layout, size = (400, 400)) # title of window

# saves the actions(clicks) and the inputted values
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event is None or event == "Exit":
        break
    
    if event == "Buy":   # Connected to Buy Function
        buy()
        print(buy())
        
        
    
window.close()
```

Comment: Function wont execute ? it executed ! Maybe only one statement `print(buy())` required when event "Buy". Just add some `print` in your `buy` function to confirm if it executed as programming.

Comment: I agree. I got it to execute the order whilst using the GUI button. I guess writing my problem helped me think it through. Thanks for your response and help!

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

After toying with it some more I decided to check whether the CoinbasePro Sandbox was fully functional. Turns out it won't execute any orders with BTC for some reason. I changed crypto to see if that made a difference. The site executed the new orders.

I played with the code again and inputted the new cryptocurrency values and rearranged some of the code blocks. Success! Got it working. I am sure there are some more improvements I can make but the code below works fine with no errors.

```
import pandas as pd
import cbpro
import PySimpleGUI as sg    

api_secret = ''
api_key =  ''
api_pass = ''

#websocket
class TextWebsocketClient(cbpro.WebsocketClient):
    def on_open(self):
        self.url           = 'wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com'  #connection endpoint
        self.message_count = 0
    
    def on_message(self,msg):   # creates message for onscreen
        self.message_count += 1
        msg_type = msg.get('type',None)
        if msg_type == 'ticker':
            # returns a dict of keys&values.
            # we then select the ones we want- 'time','price',ect
            time_val   = msg.get('time',('-'*27))
            price_val  = msg.get('price',None)
            if price_val is not None:
                price_val = float(price_val)
            product_id = msg.get('product_id',None)
            
            print(f"{time_val:40} {price_val:.3f} {product_id}\tchannel type: {msg_type}")
    
    def on_close(self):
        print(f"<---Websocket connection closed--->\n\tTotal messages: {self.message_count}")

# Closes after n messages or when loses connection
stream = TextWebsocketClient(products=['ETH-BTC'],channels=['ticker'])
stream.start()

#stream.close()
print ("Stream closed")

# creates client variable
url='https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com'

client = cbpro.AuthenticatedClient(
    api_key,
    api_secret,
    api_pass,
    api_url=url
)

#Placing a BUY market order
def buy():
    client.place_market_order(product_id='ETH-BTC',side='buy',funds=0.00003)
    return "Buy Complete"

# Gets the account history

accounts = client.get_accounts()

for acc in accounts:
    currency = acc.get('currency')
    if currency=='ETH':
        acc_id = acc.get('id')
    
acc_history = client.get_account_history(acc_id)

# GUI 
theme_name_list = sg.theme('DarkGreen')

#Buttons
layout = [ 
            [sg.Text("Welcome to your Crypto Launch Pad!\n Select a command...")],
            [sg.Button('Buy')],
            [sg.Button('Sell')],
            [sg.Button('Current Price')],
            [sg.Button('Profit/Loss')],
            [sg.Button('Exit')]
         ]
            
window = sg.Window('Crypto Buy/Sell Launch Pad', layout, size = (400, 400)) # title of window

# saves the actions(clicks) and the inputted values
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event is None or event == "Exit":
        break
    
    if event == "Buy":   # Connected to Buy Function
        buy()
    
window.close()
```